# How do I arrange the conditions so they will work simultaneously?

Tags: python, syntax, raspberry-pi3

I am new to Python and I am a still a student. I am trying to get my conditions to work at the same time. Right now the way I have it written, if the first condition is true, it does not care about the second condition. I want both conditions to be looked at with equal importance.

This is for a self watering project that goes out side. I have two zones and need them to be treated with equal importance. I have tied if/else statements and while condition statements. I know there has to be a way to go about this. Here is two versions of what I have tried so far. I know the or is bad in the first version. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
 if soil0 <10 and rc_time(phoSEN) > 4000:
    GPIO.output(relay1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay2, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(.1)
 or if soil1 <10 and rc_time(phoSEN) > 4000:
    GPIO.output(relay3, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay4, GPIO.LOW)
 else:
    GPIO.output(relay1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(relay2, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(relay3, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(relay4, GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(.1)


while soil0 <10 and rc_time(phoSEN) > 4000:
    GPIO.output(relay1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay2, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(.1) 
while soil1 <10 and rc_time(phoSEN) > 4000:
    GPIO.output(relay3, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay4, GPIO.LOW)
else:
    GPIO.output(relay1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(relay2, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(relay3, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(relay4, GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(.1)
```

Comment: Say in prose what you want to have happen. It's not entirely clear from the code.

Comment: What do you want to happen if soil0<10 AND soil1<10?

Comment: ` or if ` Do you mean else if?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to layout your conditions for this. One way that I use sometimes is to assign the result of your conditions to variables and then use these in your `if` statements

```
condition_1 = soil0 <10 and rc_time(phoSEN) > 4000
condition_2 = soil1 <10 and rc_time(phoSEN) > 4000

if condition_1:
    ...
if condition_2:
    ...
if not (condition_1 or condition_2):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed out the `sleep(.1)` section of the second condition, it may have been causing unexpected behaviour, relay3 & relay4 may have only been LOW for a tiny amount of time with no sleep statement, appearing ignored.

Also, I'm not aware that `or if` is valid syntax, I've replaced it with `elif`, since I believe that's what you mean here.

**Try this:**

```
 if soil0 <10 and rc_time(phoSEN) > 4000:
    GPIO.output(relay1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay2, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(.1)
 elif soil1 < 10 and rc_time(phoSEN) > 4000:
    GPIO.output(relay3, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(relay4, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(.1)
 else:
    GPIO.output(relay1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(relay2, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(relay3, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(relay4, GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(.1)
```